# No puedo redireccionar sitio luego de Login Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

Hola tengo el siguiente código JS para ejecutar la acción cuando se realize el inicio de sesión:

```
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
       mystatus(response);
   });

   function mystatus(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
       location.href="http://www.google.com";
     }
   }
```

Tengo todo el SDK cargado etc etc en mi sitio aparece el botón de iniciar sesión con Facebook y al completar el inicio de sesión cambia a la opción de cerrar sesión, lo que me da a entender que estoy conectado pero el código anterior no se ejecuta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenia desactivado el "Acceso del cliente de OAuth" en el panel de desarrollo de Facebook gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: sería de mucha utilidad que aceptes la respuesta haciendo un click en el check de la izquierda :D

Comment: Si lo hare pero tengo que esperar 2 días para poder hacerlo si me respondi yo mismo :o

Comment: perfecto! bienvenido a la familia de SOes, te esperamos en el chat :D

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación oficial de `Facebook`:

Te dejo el enlace: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Gestión de la respuesta del cuadro de diálogo de inicio de sesión.

En este punto del proceso de inicio de sesión la aplicación muestra el cuadro de diálogo de inicio de sesión, que ofrece a las personas la opción de cancelar o permitir a la aplicación acceder a sus datos.

Decida lo que decida la persona, el navegador vuelve a la aplicación y le comunica la decisión. Si la aplicación utiliza el SDK para JavaScript, devuelve un objeto authResponse a la dirección especificada al realizar la llamada a FB.login():

Esta respuesta puede detectarse y gestionarse dentro de la llamada a FB.login, de este modo:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

Espero que te sirva